# How to screencast my own application activity in android?

Tags: android, mobile

I want to create an interface in my application such that whatever user types or draws in that activity (in the scope of my application ) , it is recorded.
Since I don't want the recording to be done outside the scope of my application, I guess there is no need for root access.
I am thinking in the direction of taking sequence of screenshots and joining them for video.
Any leads on how to do this efficiently?

Further, one such application is present on IOS:
http://www.morriscooke.com/

Comment: Any updates on this? I am still searching for possible solutions